# AQGridView with grid outline

Tags: ios, aqgridview

I am using AQGridView to display a grid of items in my app.

Sometimes I don't have enough items to fill a row, and I wanted to add a grid outline for the cells, so you can see a 1px empty cell if you like, I could do this by hiding the content of a cell and keep the outline, but then I would have to check the index of the cell to prevent selected state etc...

Are there any other preferences that can be set to get a grid outline or should I add this myself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, maybe just use fake cells?

Comment: what do you mean by "fake cell"?